# Getting data from a web

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I would like to get the table from the web page by the link to excel:

http://www.soccerstats.com/timing.asp?league=spain

The problem is excel only gets the data on the "Total " tab, while I need two separate tables for "HOME"and "AWAY"

[image: tabs]

How can I get the data using VBA?

Comment: Try to use XHR to retrieve raw data.

Comment: Seems the standard import `From Web` on the `Data` tab does it. So, What's the problem / question? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSR8DA01jQ OR https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-external-data-from-a-Web-page-708f2249-9569-4ff9-a8a4-7ee5f1b1cfba

Answer (score 0):

This was fun. The tables `Overall, Home, Away` are actually all within an `iframe`.

I have used [Selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/) VBA, but you could easily do this without. I find the `iframe` and switch to it. An examination of the `pageSource` shows me that all tables are actually accessible from here, by tag `table`, and that the tables of interest are at indices 1-3.

After installing selenium basic you need to add a reference to selenium type library.

Code to write them all out:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTables()
    Dim d As WebDriver, i As Long, doc As New HTMLDocument, hTables As Object
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "http://www.soccerstats.com/timing.asp?league=spain"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        On Error Resume Next
        .FindElementByCss("button[onclick*=setCookielocal]").Click
        On Error GoTo 0

        .SwitchToFrame "pmatch"                  '<== Switch to iFrame
        doc.body.innerHTML = .PageSource
        Set hTables = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")

        For i = 1 To 3
            WriteTable hTables(i), GetLastRow(ActiveSheet, 1) + 1, ActiveSheet
        Next i
        .Quit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, R As Long, C As Long, tBody As Object
    R = startRow
    With ws
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            .Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
        Next header
        startRow = startRow + 1
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody               'HTMLTableSection
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
            For Each tr In tRow
                R = R + 1
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                C = 1
                For Each td In tCell             'DispHTMLElementCollection
                    .Cells(R, C).Value = "'" & td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                    C = C + 1
                Next td
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub
```